# unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address

Tags: php, android, tcp, httpurlconnection

I am developing an application in android studio and I hosted my API on AWS EC2 cloud my API is written in PHP language everything is working fine when I make a POST request on my API

but I want to shift my API from EC2 cloud to Godaddy Hosting.

But when I make a post request on Godaddy hosted API everything works fine for 10 to 15 request but after 10 to 15 request it returns me this error.

`unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@eca65bcc`

Error occurred randomly when I make post request on Godaddy hosted API.

After 10 to 20 Second Again Godaddy hosted API working fine.

But this Error not occurred in AWS Hosted API.

Please tell me the solution or I am doing something wrong ?

My Godaddy Hosting Plan : `Ultimate Hosting`

My android API connection Code -

```
URL url = new URL(api_url);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("key","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("value","UTF-8");
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); // I try this for close connection after api call but its not working
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.close();
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    result.append(line);
}
bufferedReader.close();
inputStream.close();
httpURLConnection.disconnect();
return result.toString();
```

My PHP API Code :

```
extract($_POST);
//my rest code heare
... 
...
echo json_encode($response)
```

Full Error Code :

```
2021-01-02 15:01:10.455 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@eca65bcc
2021-01-02 15:01:10.456 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:410)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.456 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:146)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.456 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:900)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.457 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:772)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.458 29700-30868/com.dailygame.app D/OpenGLRenderer: makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x700720ae00 -> 0x701b4dcf80
2021-01-02 15:01:10.457 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:493)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.459 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:429)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.459 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:252)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.461 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.dailygame.app.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:990)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.462 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.dailygame.app.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:35)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.463 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.463 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.464 29700-30868/com.dailygame.app D/OpenGLRenderer: makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x701b4dcf80 -> 0x700720ae00
2021-01-02 15:01:10.466 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.467 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.467 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.467 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.468 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
2021-01-02 15:01:10.468 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:212)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.468 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:395)
2021-01-02 15:01:10.468 29700-30863/com.dailygame.app W/System.err:     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you provide your godaddy server infos ? and is there any code that close the connection before the last echo and why are you not using exit or die after the last echo ?

Comment: i already tried exit or die but this is not working. I also talk to godaddy team they told me there is no issue from our side its your api issue. I dont know how to close connection after echo.